# Switch statement and classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, switch-statement

```
var item = $(this).attr('class');

switch (item) {
    case 'menu-visie active':
        soundManager.play('soundLaag1');
        break;
```

Is there a way, that i can remove the active in the case. The class of the variable is menu-visie active. But some times the class is menu-visie. But when the class is menu-visie. The script is not working.

How can i set the switch statement. That the statement only look at the menu-visie class. Now the class must be exactly the same

Comment: Why not simply test `if $(this).hasClass('menue-visie')` ? The goal would be clear for the readers.

Comment: Do you have other `case` statement in the same `switch`? Otherwise, I don't see why using `switch` at all.

Comment: How many cases will you have? Just two?

Comment: Hello, Thanks for you answer. But i have more than 10 different options. Is this than the best way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using jQuery to work with these classes, not manually. For example:

```
if ($(this).hasClass('menu-visie')) {
  soundManager.play('soundLaag1');
}
```

**UPDATE**
If you have many classes, I would create an object to store them all. For example:

```
var self = this,
    sounds = {
      'menu-visie':'soundLaag1',
      'menu-visie2':'soundLaag2'
    };

$.each(sounds, function(i,n) {
  if (self.hasClass(i)) {
    soundManager.play(n);
  }
});
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for you answer. But i have more than 10 different options. Is this than the best way?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
if($(this).hasClass('menu-visie')) {
    soundManager.play('soundLaag1');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this instead:

```
if( $(this).hasClass('menu-visie') ) {
    soundManager.play('soundLaag1');
} else {
    //something else.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As most has mentioned you should use the Jquery method "hasClass". If you still want to keep your switch (if you have many statements) you can write your code like this:

```
switch (true) {
    case $(this).hasClass('menu-visie'):
        soundManager.play('soundLaag1');
        break;
```

Comment: I see this as an uncomfortable use of a switch statement, and thus the meaning of the logical expression is obscured.

Comment: You can debate wether a switch is really needed here. If there's not more than 2 cases, then an if/else would be more proper. Using switch'es with true as the expression is something that can always be debated (and has been). I wrote this as the title contains "Switch statement and classes". It's an alternative.